# Why we do not see an error when input (or #t (/ 1 0)) in Racket shell?

Tags: racket, evaluation

```
(or #t (/ 1 0))
```

`(/ 1 0)` is illegle, but why we do not see an error?

There's an explanation in my lecture note.

> The identifier `or` does not refer to a function, but rather a
>   syntactic form that implements short-circuiting.

But I still don't quite understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part is that `or` is a *syntactic form*, as mentioned in your lecture notes. That means that the evaluation rules are different from a normal procedure, and can be implemented at the interpreter level or (more likely) as a derived expression or a macro. If we tried to implement `or` as a procedure, your example would indeed fail:

```
(define (my-or a b)
  (if a a b))

(my-or #t (/ 1 0))
=> /: division by zero
```

Procedures evaluate all its arguments before passing them to the body . By contrast, `or` evaluates its first argument, if it's truthy it returns the value of the first argument, otherwise it returns the result of evaluating the second argument - but it'll *never* evaluate the second argument if the first one was truthy. This is known as "short circuit" evaluation of boolean connectors, and something similar happens with `and`.

To gain a better understanding of what's happening under the hood, please read chapter 4 of SICP, here's the relevant link explaining [derived expressions](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1.2). Quoting: "Some special forms in our language can be defined in terms of expressions involving other special forms, rather than being implemented directly". In this case, `or` can be implemented using `if`, which in turn is also a syntactic form, implemented as a special case in the interpreter's evaluation procedure.